# ILMerge exited with code -1073741701

Tags: .net, msbuild, ilmerge

I have a C# project where I run ILMerge in the AfterBuild target. However, I have a message telling me that my command failed and exited with code -1073741701.

The strange thing to me is that if I run the command written in the output in a command prompt, it succeeds. Any idea ?

One tip : I am using ILMerge to merge projects built for silverlight with a "classic" .NET project. You can find this project on http://euss.codeplex.com. The project causing me troubles is Evaluant.Uss.PersistenceEngine.Contracts

Here is the msbuild I run to create my ilmerge command

```
<CreateItem Include="@(ReferencePath)" Condition="'%(CopyLocal)'=='false' and '$(FwkLibPath)\.'!='%(RootDir)%(Directory).'">
  <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="libPaths" />
</CreateItem>
<CreateItem Include="@(ReferencePath)" Condition="'%(CopyLocal)'=='true'">
  <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="IlmergeAssemblies" />
</CreateItem>
<Exec Command="&quot;$(SolutionDir)Dependencies\ILMerge\Ilmerge.exe&quot; /target:library /lib:&quot;$(FwkLibPath)&quot; @(libPaths->'/lib:&quot;%(RootDir)%(Directory).&quot;', ' ') &quot;/targetplatform:v2,$(FwkLibPath)&quot; /out:&quot;$(MergedOutDir)$(RootNamespace)$(Suffix)&quot; &quot;$(ProjectDir)@(IntermediateAssembly)&quot; @(IlmergeAssemblies->'&quot;%(FullPath)&quot;', ' ')" />
```

It generates the following in the output window :

```
P:\Developpement\euss\Dev\ProvideMultiplatformVersions.proj(42,5): error MSB3073: The command ""P:\Developpement\euss\Dev\Dependencies\ILMerge\Ilmerge.exe" /target:library /lib:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727" /lib:"P:\Developpement\euss\Dev\Assemblies\." "/targetplatform:v2,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727" /out:"P:\Developpement\euss\Dev\Assemblies\Net\Evaluant.Uss.PersistenceEngine.Contracts.dll" "P:\Developpement\euss\Dev\Evaluant.Uss.PersistenceEngine.Contracts\obj\Debug\Evaluant.Uss.PersistenceEngine.Contracts.dll" "P:\Developpement\euss\Dev\Evaluant.Uss.Commands\bin\Debug\Evaluant.Uss.Commands.dll" "P:\Developpement\euss\Dev\Evaluant.Uss.Commands\bin\Debug\Evaluant.Uss.Domain.dll" "P:\Developpement\euss\Dev\Evaluant.Uss.Commands\bin\Debug\Evaluant.Uss.Era.dll" "P:\Developpement\euss\Dev\Evaluant.Uss.Metadata\bin\Debug\Evaluant.Uss.MetaData.dll" "P:\Developpement\euss\Dev\Evaluant.Uss.Commands\bin\Debug\Evaluant.Uss.MetaData.Light.dll" "P:\Developpement\euss\Dev\Evaluant.Uss.Commands\bin\Debug\Evaluant.Uss.Model.dll" "P:\Developpement\euss\Dev\Evaluant.Uss.PersistenceEngine.Contracts\bin\Debug\Evaluant.Uss.PersistenceEngine.Contracts.Instrumentation.dll" "P:\Developpement\euss\Dev\Evaluant.Uss.Commands\bin\Debug\Evaluant.Uss.PersistentDescriptors.dll" "P:\Developpement\euss\Dev\Evaluant.Uss.Serializer\bin\Debug\Evaluant.Uss.Serializer.dll" "P:\Developpement\euss\Dev\Evaluant.Uss.Commands\bin\Debug\Evaluant.Uss.Utility.dll"" exited with code -1073741701.
```

If I copy paste this command (without the surrounding quotes), it works.

Comment: Is it a .Net2 or .Net 4 build? Can it be a resource gen issue?

Comment: .NET 2, and I have no resource in any project of this solution

Comment: FWIW, -1073741701, i.e. `0xC000007B` is code `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`. Could you post the command lines you use from both `AfterBuild` and from the command line? Are you sure you use the same input files from both?

Comment: Just edited my question so you can better understand

Comment: If I add the log parameter to a specific file, no log is created when in visual, and in the command prompt the full log is generated

Comment: Additionnal data : if I run msbuild Evaluant.Uss.PersistenceEngine.Contracts.csproj with commandline, it tells me "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like ilmerge does not support being called within another process :

- if I run it with msbuild, it crashes with error code 0xC000007B
- If I run it with msbuild as an admin, it crashes with the same error
- if I force ilmerge to run as an admin and run msbuild as a standard user, I have a new command prompt opened for ilmerge and it succeeds
- If I run ilmerge without msbuild as a standard user, it succeeds

Comment: It was an issue with my .NET installation. I switched to another windows and it works perfectly.